# Is fixed array size O(n) or O(1) in space?

Tags: arrays, big-o, space-complexity

Is an array declared like this:
`int array[M]`, `O(1)` in space or `O(n)`? where M is some fixed value. To me `O(n)` makes sense because it is not just a single variable but an entire array. But then i think it could be `O(1)` since we have a fixed size and it is not changing!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your array is of a fixed size and it does not vary with the size of the input it is `O(1)` since it can be expressed as `c * O(1)` = `O(1)`, with `c` being some constant. An example would be if you needed an array of size 5 to hold state in your algorithm that runs over a million (or some other arbitrary number) integers. The important thing is `M` and `N` are independent.

If however `M` represents the size of your input or a value that is directly dependent of the input size (i.e. `N/2` or some other linear function), then really `M` grows along with your `N`, the input size so it would be `O(N)`. An example would be an array that holds all input numbers of which you want to run an algorithm over (i.e determining the sum of the squares).

Comment: I think he meant that the absolute space consumption is c*1 for some c, which is a subset of the complexity set O(1) (since you drop the constant factor). But that's mostly syntax anyway.

Comment: when you say 'absolute space' does that mean space can be negative?

Comment: @rashid: space can never be negative, at best you consume no space.

Comment: i was thinking in terms of math, like when we say absolute value of a negative number. :)

Comment: I meant absolute as opposed to asymptotic.

Answer (score 1):

I would say O(1) when M is a constant. If it is O(n) its size must be linear function of M, which in this case is not.

Comment: ah, so that means if we were to graph it we would see a line with a zero slope implying that the space complexity is constant, am i right?

Comment: What is confusing is the fact that you say M which sounds like variable, but in fact it is a constant. So your situation is no different from int[6] - which is constant size obviously. You just decided you will call M the 6. When it comes to graph it will be constant function, thats right.

Comment: that is why i said M is a fixed value! :)

Comment: But when you graph it don't get fooled and use M as an variable of one of your graph axis. It is NOT a variable :)

Answer (score 0):

The other answers you were given are correct, formally it's **O(1)**.

But think very carefully about the meaning of "constant". The O(...) notation is not meant to measure the performance of an actual computer program, but to categorize algorithms by complexity.

If you are implementing an algorithm that works on an array of objects reading each of them only once (for example), you may say "ok, let's fix the number of elements to N", but that won't move the algorithm into the O(1) complexity class, the algorithm is still O(n) but you're limiting your test cases to n = N where N is fixed.