# space complexity for queue with fixed size

Tags: java, algorithm, queue

Currently, I am studying space and time complexity analysis. I have a question.
If we create a queue, we know we only need this queue to maintain 5000 elements at most. 
The space complexity for this queue should be O(1)?

Comment: Space and time complexity is determined by implementation, so your question cannot be answered in general, but space complexity for any structure that stores N elements can be less than O(N). it may greater though. Hence, it cannot be O(1) anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the constraints of your problem, no matter how many operations you perform, your queue never exceeds 5000 elements, so its size is bounded by a constant (5000). That's the definition of O(1) size complexity.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't really studied space complexity as extensively as I did for time complexity. My research comes from https://www.quora.com/How-do-we-calculate-space-complexity

As we add to the queue of Size < 5000 the space complexity of the queue would be O(N), I would think. You are growing the queue which will take up N*(Size of element) bytes.

> If my queue size is > 5000, then I will poll the top element from the queue and add a new element into the queue. Will that operation affect the space complexity for my queue?

If your queue was at max capacity (5000), and you were to remove the first element of the queue as you added more elements, then the overall size stays the same. Adding additional elements once queue reaches max capacity is now O(1).

Answer (score 0):

It depends, if you somehow take all the space needed for the queue to hold all the 5000 elements, or just start with one that has 5000 element already, then is `O(1)` space complex. And it would be something like an [array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5872570/is-fixed-array-size-on-or-o1-in-space) at this point.

However if you start with zero nodes and you keep adding nodes to the structure, then it would be `O(n)` complex since a queue is dynamic in that sense, regardless the fact you will have 5000 max elements.

[Here](http://bigocheatsheet.com/) is a nice complexity cheatsheet by the way.

Comment: thanks for your reply. If my queue size is > 5000, then I will poll the top element from the queue and add a new element into the queue. Will that operation affect the space complexity for my queue?

Comment: No, one element won't make the difference in space complexity analysis.